# Django: Display a PDF document in iframe or embed not working

Tags: html, django, pdf, iframe

I want to display a PDF on on a page in our website. The URL is correct and pointing to the PDF. I am seeing a display, but I see garbage characters instead of the PDF.

In template using:

```
<embed src="{{packet.certificate_pdf.url}}" ...>
<iframe src="{{packet.certificate_pdf.url}}" ...>
```

Then I see results on the page where the PDF is suppose to display:

```
%PDF-1.3
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
/Count 6
/Kids [ 3 0 R 4 0 R 5 0 R 6 0 R 7 0 R 8 0 R ]
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/Producer (PyPDF4)
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/MediaBox [ 0 0 595 842 ]
/Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/Contents [ 10 0 R ]
/Resources <<
/ProcSet [ /PDF /Text /ImageC ]
/XObject <<
/HiQPdf_mlpnjcimdfejkpcopajmiphnnjaiocbm 11 0 R
>>
>>
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
/MediaBox [ 0 0 
.... etc
```

Using in Production enviroment:
Django 3.2
Python 3.8
Already using: X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'

I also tried converting to base64 then displaying it:

```
<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,{{pdf_in_base64}} ...
```

This used to work, but recently Chrome sometimes show the PDF and sometimes not, which I can't solve. Something in the base64 seems to break the PDF display intermittendly. So now I am trying to use URL directly instead of base64.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: In the view serving the pdf, have you set the content-type header to `application/pdf`?

Comment: Hi Tim. I tried adding conent-type for both iframe and embed like this example, but not success. <iframe type="application/pdf" ...